# Correctness of Fisher-Yates Shuffle Executed Backward

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, probability, shuffle, pseudocode

According to wikipedia and also the implementation of Java standard library, shuffling [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Yates_shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) (Fisher Yates Shuffling) works like this:

Algo A:

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from n−1 downto 1 do
     j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
     exchange a[j] and a[i]
```

or equivalently

Algo B:

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from 0 to n−2 do
     j ← random integer such that i ≤ j < n
     exchange a[i] and a[j]
```

My question is for the one below (Algo C):

Algo C:

```
-- To shuffle an array a of n elements (indices 0..n-1):
for i from 1 to n−1 do
     j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i
     exchange a[i] and a[j]
```

Algo A and Algo B are just identical. But Algo C is different from Algo A and Algo B (in fact Algo C is Algo A executed in reverse direction)

Is Algo C correct? I am very confused. I did some chi-squared test using contingency table, and it appears that this gives apparently correct uniform order.

My question is whether Algo C is correct? If correct, why is it seen almost no where? Why F-Y shuffle is everywhere presented in one same direction.

Comment: Well. Someone thinks as I do. https://possiblywrong.wordpress.com/2020/12/10/the-fisher-yates-shuffle-is-backward/ I think Algo C is correct.

Comment: Esoteric: why do you exclude index zero in A and C? Also `exchange a[i] and a[j]` is of course the same as `exchange a[j] and a[i]`.

Comment: Well, when i = 0, j is certainly 0. There is no need of exchanging them.

Comment: Algo C is certainly not what you want. For n=2, it will always return the reverse of the original array, never the original. Are you sure that is the code you want us to look at?

Comment: @congyuwang: Right, but that's true for any time that `i == j`, no?

Comment: @trincot That's wrong, because there is a 50% probability of generating `j = i` and not swapping.

Comment: @trincot Algorithm C says `j ← random integer such that 0 ≤ j ≤ i` where `≤` is not `<`. So `i` is a possible value for `j`.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the last edit to the question. The OP has corrected it. Not sure why I didn't get the banner at the top notifying me of the OP's change.

Comment: @trincot OK, I figured since your comment was several minutes after the edit that you were looking at the current version, but my apologies.

Comment: Very interesting question, however, cs.stackexchange.com is a better forum for questions like that. That said, maybe one way to look at it is to investigate in general whether the inverse of a permutation has some or any of the properties (such as randomness) of the permutation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing on why it isn't seen more (as the other answer already shows that it is correct).

The variants are useful as optimizations in various cases:

- Algo B is useful if you only want a few of the random elements. Think shuffling a deck and handing out a few hands, and then collecting all the cards to reshuffle. With Algo B you don't have to shuffle the hands that weren't dealt.
- Algo A is useful because you can skip the initialization, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_%22inside-out%22_algorithm
- Algo C would be useful if the collection isn't known in advanced, but this seems pretty esoteric. (So you randomly shuffle 5 cards, and then get a new one, take one more step, and then you have 6 shuffled cards etc.)

Those additional uses mean that Algo B and A will be coded more, and used even in other cases.

Comment: Great. It makes sense. A lot of application also has sample(k) API, so Algo A and Algo B supports sampling k out of n with equal probability, while Algo C cannot do that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this algorithm is correct, as it has a [loop invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_invariant) that each permutation of the first `i` elements is equally likely. The invariant is initially satisfied when `i = 1` because there is only one possible permutation of one element, and then when `i = n` (i.e. after the last iteration of the loop) each permutation of the whole array is equally likely.

To see why the invariant holds, we only need to consider a single iteration of the loop. Suppose the first `i` elements have all permutations equally likely, and we swap the first unshuffled element (call it `x`) with a random index up to or including itself. Now consider any two permutations P1 and P2 of the first `i + 1` elements of the initial array: let Q1 and Q2 be the permutations of the first `i` elements which would result from swapping `x` in P1 and P2 respectively to index `i`. Since both Q1 and Q2 are equally likely by the inductive hypothesis, and both swaps are equally likely, and the *only* way P1 or P2 can happen is by these swaps starting from Q1 or Q2 respectively, it follows that P1 and P2 are equally likely to be the result.

---

So your algorithm is correct, but probably not well-known like Fisher–Yates because it has no advantages over Fisher–Yates, while being less obviously correct. Also worth noting is that it's easy to adapt Fisher–Yates to uniformly sample `k < n` distinct elements from the array in O(k) time, whereas your algorithm cannot be adapted in this way.